# Java arraycopy specific area of a two dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

I started coding java about 2 weeks ago,and need some help with my code.
I have an 4x4 array

```
[0][1][2][3]
[4][5][6][7]
[8][9][10][11]
[11][12][13][14]
```

I want to copy a part of the array to newArray,which is 2x2, for example {[9][10];[12][13]}
But this code only copies values from the first two rows,while I need the third and fourth

```
int[][]newArray=new int[2][2];
for (int i =0; i < newArray.length; i++) {           
 System.arraycopy(array[i], 1, newArray[i], 0, newArray[0].length);
        }
```

Cheers,and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set an offset into the outer array; for example:

```
int[][]newArray=new int[2][2];
int offset = 2;
for (int i =0; i < newArray.length; i++) {           
    System.arraycopy(array[i + offset], 1, newArray[i], 0, newArray[0].length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] array = { { 0, 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6, 7 }, { 8, 9, 10, 11 },
            { 11, 12, 13, 14 } };
    int[][] newArray = new int[2][2];
    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < newArray[i].length; j++) {
            newArray[i][j] = array[2 + i][1 + j];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(newArray));
}
```

Output is

```
[[9, 10], [12, 13]]
```